# Виснет дев тулс любого браузера. Как дебажить другими способами?

Tags: javascript

Привет.

Бывают ситуации, когда при исполнении какого-то скрипта браузер зависает вместе со своим девтулс. При этом, я не могу узнать, где же в скрипте ошибка, ведь девтусл завис. Приходится закомментировать разные куски кода и отлавливать место с ошибкой таким образом.

Например, в данный момент дебажу скрипт, скрипт заставляет зависнуть ЛЮБОЙ браузер. И девтулс любого браузера не работает.

Что можно сделать?

До ответа уже додумался. Зависание браузера вызывает не бесконечная рекурсия (она вызывает ошибку - переполнение стека контекстов выполнения, а не зависание браузера), а бесконечный цикл. Чтобы отловить СРАЗУ, какой именно из десятков циклов в программе бесконечно зациклился, можно вместо циклов использовать, например, рекурсивную функцию. Например, вместо цикла

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i=i+1) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Написать рекурсивную функцию

```
var i=0; 

function cycle(){
  console.log(i); 
  i=i+1;

  if(i==5) 
    return; 

  cycle()
};

cycle();
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43982/discussion-on-question-by-dimon--------).

Answer (score 4):

К сожалению, отладчики скрипта в *некоторых* современных браузерах слишком чувствительны к некоторым ошибкам в отлаживаемом коде.

Например, следующий скрипт вполне убивает Chrome 52 и Edge 20.

```
var j=0; 

function cycle(){
    if (j > 5)
        return;

    for (var i = 0; i<100000; i++)
    {
        j = j + 1;
        cycle();
        j = j - 1;
    }
};

cycle();
```

Под Windows есть два варианта решения проблемы:

- Взять старый добрый Firefox. Он через пару секунд выполнения понимает, что что-то пошло не так, и предлагает остановить и отладить скрипт.
- Взять IE + внешний отладчик (Visual Studio). Включить в настройках IE отладку скриптов, воспроизвести проблемную ситуацию, прицепиться к процессу студией и остановить выполнение.